# Why does Enumerable.Aggregate exist with resultSelector overload?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm wondering what purpose of this overload

```
public static TResult Aggregate<TSource,TAccumulate,TResult> (
    this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate,TSource,TAccumulate> func,
    Func<TAccumulate,TResult> resultSelector);
```

Compared to

```
public static TAccumulate Aggregate<TSource,TAccumulate> (
    this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate,TSource,TAccumulate> func);
```

It seems rather redundant to have the `resultSelector` overload when you could just process the returned  `TAccumulate` instead. Are there any benefits I'm missing?

Comment: Basically it's the difference between `var x = points.Aggregate(seed, (a, p) => a + p, p => p.X);` and `var x = points.Aggregate(seed, (a, p) => a + p).X`.  Basically it only returns the value you're interested in after the aggregation is done.

Comment: Because most of the time, people are whining about *missing* overloads, so the LINQ folk said, "let's just throw everything in there, that'll shut them up".

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything, it is redundant and not very useful. If you look at the source code, it simply does this at the end:

```
return resultSelector(result);
```

Perhaps the rationale was to make the API more consistent with the related `SelectMany` method which also takes an optional result selector (and where it actually makes a difference).

Or perhaps to allow a more fluent syntax - though it's questionable if using this overload really makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Yes good point, I didn't think of that. I have been a bit bothered by not knowing the reasoning behind this overload.